# EmberJS - Iterating over return value of a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a property (months) which calls a function which returns an range of numbers in an array.

```
months: function()
{           
    var range = this._makeRange(1, 13);
    return range;
},
```

Where the result of range would be something like

```
[
    { value: 1, number: '01' },
    ...
]
```

But when I want to iterate over it with the each helper like this:

```
{{#each months}}
    Current Month - {{number}}    
{{/each}}
```

It gives the following error:

`Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () {`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: months cannot be a function, either define it as property or computed property. Others could help you better if you create a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ of your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

months must be a property, not a function

```
months: function()
{           
    var range = this._makeRange(1, 13);
    return range;
}.property(),
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pihigaya/1/edit

Comment: That was indeed my initial thought, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: looks like it works in my jsbin, are you sure it's returning an array?

Comment: It looks like it works when directly returning the array in the method. But calling a method which returns an array doesn't seem to work. See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pihigaya/8/edit

Comment: sure it does, you're failing to return the results of the function in that jsbin, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pihigaya/9/edit